# Comparing Dictionaries and finding new objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I need to compare two dictionaries x and y.
How to find that dictionary y is having some new elements which are not available in dictionary x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LINQ`

```
        Dictionary<int, object> x = new()
        {
            {0,null },
            {1,null },
            {7,null },
            {4,null }
        };

        Dictionary<int, object> y = new(x); // new y with x values
        y.Add(3, null);
        foreach(var e in y.Except(x)){
            Console.WriteLine(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

using `linq` you can do

```
bool yContainsNew = y.Any(kv => !(x.ContainsKey(kv.Key) && x[kv.Key] == kv.Value));
```

Comment: `TryGetValue` may be of interest.

Comment: `bool yContainsNew = y.Any(kv => !x.TryGetValue(kv.Key, out var value) || value != kv.Value);` either we don't have `kv.Key` at all or `kv.Value` is different then corresponding one in `x` dictionary